# TYPO3: Inject Service Classes into AuthServiceClass with Constructor

Tags: php, authentication, dependency-injection, typo3, extbase

I'm using TYPO3 10.2 and trying to inject some Service Classes that I created into my authentication service.

```
class AuthService extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationService
```

The Constructor in AuthService:

```
    /**
     * Contains the configuration of the current extension
     * @var ConfigurationService
     */
    protected $configurationService;

    /**
     * @var RestClientService
     */
    protected $restClientService;

    /**
     * @var ConnectionPool
     */
    protected $connectionPool;

    /**
     * 
     * @param ConfigurationService $configurationService
     * @param RestClientService $restClientService
     * @param ConnectionPool $connectionPool
     */
    public function __construct(ConfigurationService $configurationService, RestClientService $restClientService, ConnectionPool $connectionPool)
    {
        $this->configurationService = $configurationService;

        $this->restClientService = $restClientService;

        $this->connectionPool = $connectionPool;
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Too few arguments to function Vendor\MyExt\Service\AuthService::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 3461 and exactly 3 expected

Any advice what's going on here?

I used the same Constructor in my ControllerClass and everything is working fine there.

Thanks so far!

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar with Typo3, but looking at [the docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#configure-dependency-injection-in-extensions), did you set up your service to have its `autowire` property activated?

Comment: yes autowiring is set up correctly, the other classes are working fine aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `AuthenticationService` is internally instantiated by `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()`. This is true for many classes that you register at some point and TYPO3 then takes care of the creation of the class (think of user functions, plugin controller, module controller, authentication services, hooks, etc).

`GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` needs to get the class out of the DI container for the DI to work but this is only possible for classes made `public` during container compilation.

For that reason the solution to your problem should be to declare the class `AuthService` as public in your `Configuration/Services.yaml`:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  Vendor\MyExt\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'

  Vendor\MyExt\Service\AuthService:
    public: true
```

You can find this explained in the [official docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#knowing-what-to-make-public) or in my [blog post](https://usetypo3.com/dependency-injection.html) about that topic.

Comment: thanks, this one worked but I got another issues. I want to inject  the ConfigurationManagerInterface into one of my Service Classes which are by default configured with autoconfigure: true. Now iam not able to get the typoscript settings/configuration. In the typo3 docs it its recommended to keep that option true, how do I deal with this one ?